# Expected number of runs when there are $n_1$ objects of one kind and $n_2$ objects of second kind. Flaw in Argument?

Tags: probability, runs

Suppose there are $n_1$ objects of one kind and $n_2$ objects of the second kind. These objects appear randomly in a sequence. I want to find the expected number of runs in the sequence.

**Attempt**: Define the variable $Y_i$ as

\begin{cases} 
      1 & i\text{th elements is different from } (i-1)th \\
      0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}

The number of runs $R = 1 + \sum_{2}^n Y_i$

$\implies \mathbb E[R] = 1 + \sum_2^n P(Y_i) \text{where } n = n_1 + n_2$

To calculate $P(Y_i) : $ the following argument :

$i$th position can be occupied by either Type-$1$ object in which case, the $i-1$th object must be occupied by type $2$ object. This happens in $n_1 \times n_2$ ways

Similarly when $i$th position is occupied by Type-$2$ object, the $(i-1)$th object must be occupied by type $1$ object which also happens in $n_1 \times n_2 $ ways

Summing up the required probability is $\dfrac{2 \times n_1 n_2}{^nC_2}$ and hence $\mathbb E[R] = 1 + \sum_2^n \dfrac{2 \times n_1 n_2}{^nC_2}$.

> **But the book which I am reading seems to exclude $2$ from the
> numerator and states required probability as $\dfrac{n_1 n_2}{^nC_2}$.**

**Could this be a typo? Thanks!**

Comment: Try $n_1=2$ of one kind and $n_2=1$ of the other.   The expected number of runs is $\frac23\times 2 + \frac13\times 3=\frac73$  or in your expression $1+\frac23+\frac23$ where $\frac23=\frac{2\times 1}{^3C_2}$ as the book has.  I would not have written $\dfrac{n_1 n_2}{^nC_2}$ but $2\dfrac{n_1 n_2}{n(n-1)}$ which you then multiply by $(n-1)$ and add $1$ to give $\mathbb E[R]=1+\dfrac{2n_1 n_2}{n}$

Comment: In R, the procedure `rle` (for run length encoding) gives two vectors for a sample `x`: the number of runs, and the numerical values of each run. Thus if we count the number runs of Hs and Ts when tossing a fair coin 100 times, the R code `set.seed(2021); 
nr.run = replicate(10^5, length(rle(rbinom(100,1,.5))$val));
mean(nr.run)` returns $50.49598.$